# Is mkWeak strict in its value argument?

Tags: haskell

The function `mkWeak` is useful for building various low-level abstractions in Haskell. (See [here](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Mem-Weak.html) for documentation.) It was not clear to me what the behavior was when it is passed a (key, value) pair where the value is an unevaluated thunk. Will it evaluate the thunk before making the weak pointer, or is it held unevaluated. I'm sure that there's some clever expression I can type involving `undefined` to resolve this one way or the other, but I can't think what it is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember, a strict function has to return bottom if given bottom as an argument, so you can test the strictness of a function by giving it `undefined` as an argument and observing whether you get an exception or not.

A quick experiment indicates that `mkWeak` is not strict in its second argument. (And I don't see a good reason why it would be, anyway).

```
Prelude System.Mem.Weak> mkWeak "foo" undefined Nothing
Prelude System.Mem.Weak>
```

Comment: D'oh! I was forgetting to include the `Nothing` and misinterpreting the resulting error message. Thanks for setting me straight! I agree that it really ought to be lazy :)